# GitHub Actions: How to trigger a workflow on a pull_request event filtered on the name of the merging branch

Tags: github-actions

OK I've seen at least 1 solution on this but it isn't as elegant as it should be IMO so I'm holding out hope that I'm just not understanding the documentation.

##### Preamble

A pull request involves 2 branches, a "source" and a "destination", if you will. If you look at the top of the pull request on Git Hub you will see two branches with an arrow between them. "Source" will be at the tail of the arrow and "destination" will be at the point of the arrow.

There is a workflow trigger called `pull_request` that, by default, triggers whenever a pull request is opened wherein the "destination" (the branch at the point of the arrow) is the main/master branch. It is possible to change this such that the workflow would trigger whenever a pull request is opened wherein the "destination" branch is something other than main/master by simply using `branches:`

##### Question

How does one configure a workflow to trigger based on the "source" (the branch at the tail of the arrow)?

The solution I have seen (and it works) is to put a conditional on the job, like so

```
jobs:
  my-job:
    if:  startsWith(github.head_ref, '<source branch name>')
```

but, as I said, I'm hoping there is actually a way to do this that is equally as elegant as the way it is done for the "destination" branch of a pull request.

Comment: I don't think that there's a more "built-in" way to check the head branch than a job-level if-clause.

Comment: It both surprises and confuses me that one would be implemented, but not the other, so thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Wouldn't the `branches` subtype for push and pull_request triggers be the solution in your case? Something like `on: push: branches: [<source-branch>]` or `on: pull_request: branches: [<source-branch>]`. Anyway, the check at the job level is still a good solution from my point of view to filter the specific scenario.

Comment: @GuiFalourd `branches:` applies to the base branch, which is the "destination" in this question, no?

Comment: For the `pull_request` I guess it is like this yes, but if you want to workflow to trigger each time you open or update the PR, you could use the `on: push: branches: [<branch>]` using the destination branch instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only possible using the conditional on the job.